# Array Checksum Algorithm - Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, checksum

I have been working on problem 17 at Code Abbey. The task is to find the checksum of an array.

I would appreciate an explanation as to why the answer is correct and why my solution is not working.

[This is the problem:](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/array-checksum)

> You will be given the array for which checksum should be calculated. Perform calculation as follows: for each element of the array (starting from beginning) add this element to `result` variable and multiply this sum by `113` - this new value taken by modulo `10000007` should become the next value of `result`, and so on.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> input data:
> 6
> 3 1 4 1 5 9
>
> answer:
> 8921379
> ```
>
> All input values are between `0` and `1,000,000,000` - be sure to take care of possible overflow in progress of calculations.

This is my attempt:

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

def get_checksum(a):
    seed = 113
    limit = 10000007
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        result += a[i]
        result *= seed
        result %= limit

    return result

print(get_checksum(a))
```

Comment: This misses the last element, try range(len(a))

Comment: or better yet, skip indexing entirely and do `for item in a:`

Comment: 6235989 is what my code produces with the test cases provided (new test cases are provided at random each time the page is refreshed), but the correct answer (again, with the current test array as input) is 4669996.  Also, the reason I subtract one from the length of the array, is for indexing purposes, i.e. a[0].

Comment: What do you guys think of my algorithm?  Obviously, I'm doing something wrong because I get the wrong answer every time.  However, I followed the directions exactly as given by the author...  Either the author didn't do a good job of explaining the algorithm, or I missed something or am just plain doing something wrong.  Provided that the author of this exercise is a much better programmer than I, I'm going to go with the latter :/

Comment: You're going to have to give us a test case, 'cause I'm just going with the one on the linked page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add another object to the end of the array you get the right answer:

```
a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, "X"]

def get_checksum(a):
    seed = 113
    limit = 10000007
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        result += a[i]
        result *= seed
        result %= limit

    return result

print(get_checksum(a))
#>>> 8921379
```

so as Peter de Rivaz says it's because you're missing the last element. Take Kevin's answer and just loop over the items in `a`:

```
a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]

def get_checksum(a):
    seed = 113
    limit = 10000007
    result = 0

    for item in a:
        result += item
        result *= seed
        result %= limit

    return result

print(get_checksum(a))
#>>> 8921379
```

Comment: Wow... I feel like a complete loser now... Classic rookie mistake... However, I actually do feel really good about the fact the I pretty much had the algorithm correct.  It always seems to be the smallest, simplest little detail...  So, big, big thanks to Kevin, Peter de Rivaz, and Veedrac!  I appreciate you guys taking the time to look over my code and give me helpful explanations, rather than make fun of me for my rookie mistake.  Oh, and Veedrac, thank you for editing my post; As this is my first post, I'll be mindful of following this template in future posts.  Thanks again, guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_checksum(a):
    seed = 113
    limit = 10000007
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(a)):
        result += a[i]
        result *= seed
        result %= limit

    return result

    print(get_checksum([3, 1, 4, 1, 5 , 9]))
```

This prints out `8921379`.